# Empty parameters hash when doing XML requests. request.content_type is indeed application/xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, request, content-type

My actions are behaving strangely. All requests I do with XML content type (through cURL, ActiveResource, you name it) have empty `params[]` inside my actions. I debugged `request.content_type` and it is `application/xml`. Debugging `request.body.read` shows that the XML that I sent in the request is there too.

Interestingly enough, debugging `request.formats` returns `[*/*]`.

I also tried to add a simple Rack middleware at the beggining of my stack and the `CONTENT_TYPE` is right there in my env variable, with it's correct value.

With this problem, my request body never gets parsed and I always get into the `format.html` block of my `respond_to` call.

I inspected `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser` and the params are being built correctly there and placed into `env["action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"]`. However they end up as an empty `params[]` in my actions (just for non HTML requests, i.e. JSON, XML, etc).

Any ideas of what can be wrong? Thanks!

In the meantime, I found a solution myself: It was some strange combination of memcache-client being used for session store in my app. It worked on my co-worker Ubuntu box. I replaced memcache-client with dalli and changed the session store to configuration to explicitely set the memcache server host as the localhost. It worked.

Comment: try to request /your/resource/something.xml (appending .xml)

Comment: That's exactly what ActiveResource does. Also, appending .xml through curl yields the same result. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue and your question gave me some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this gem: `actionpack-xml_parser`. I think this gem will resolve your query because I had the same issue it was able to resolve it with this.